# Extending Array hides initializer?

Tags: ruby

I'm using ruby 1.8.7

```
my_array = Array.new(5, "A")
```

works fine.  However if I extend the Array class like this:

```
class Array
  def my_function
    self
  end
end
```

then the initializer no longer works and returns

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
```

Why is this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Are you doing this inside a `Module`? If so, you are defining a separate `Array` class, rather than extending `Array` from the standard library.

Make sure your extension is at the top level, or else write:

```
class ::Array
```

(By the way, is there a good reason why you want to use Ruby 1.8.7? If not, I would recommend using an up-to-date version -- Ruby has improved over the years.)

Comment: I inherited this really badly designed and implemented rails project (2.3.5) and upgrading about anything causing things to fall over.  
The Array extension is defined in a model class.  Pushing it to global scope with ::Array works, however then the extension method stops working.  
The method is used like this: MyActiveRecord.find(criteria).my_function

Comment: I'm pretty sure "find" returns an Array.  So why doesn't this work? Error message is "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)"

Comment: Ah! No, I don't think `ActiveRecord::Base.find` returns an Array. Try `Model.find(criteria).class` in the Rails console to check. Whatever the class returned is, define your extension method on that. Make sure you don't define a separate class.